# MVC 3 razor form setting value in model with out user interaction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm new to MVC 3 and am having some difficulty with my razor form.  The form is used for a test.  It has about 100 questions on it.  The questions have only 2 possible answers.  I have a model that contains the answers to the questions.  Each answer has 3 possible settings.  1 for answer 1. 2 for answer 2. And 0 if it has never been answered.  The problem is that when I post the form the answers are getting set to 1 even if no answer was provided.

Here is the code:

Top of the form

```
@model CSO.Legacy.Web.MBTIMAssessment

<div id ="MBTIMAsessment"> 

@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveMBTIM", "Assessment"))
{
```

The radio buttons

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Answer1, "1")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Answer1, "2")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Answer2, "1")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Answer2, "2")
```

the submit button

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="btn-submit-for-review btn" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit();"></a>
```

from the model

```
public string Answer1 { get; set ; }
public string Answer2 { get; set ; }
public string Answer3 { get; set; }
```

from the controller

```
public void SaveMBTIM(MBTIMAssessment assessment)
{
    assessment.SubmitAssessment();
}
```

Thanks in advance

Wizy

Answer (score 0):

You could add a "no selection" option:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Answer1, "no selection", new { Checked = "checked" })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Answer1, "1")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Answer1, "2")
```

It's not really a MVC thing:

```
<input type="radio" name="group" value="a" />
<input type="radio" name="group" value="b" />

$('input[type=radio]').val(): // "a"
```

Even if neither are selected.